# Creating action on google | Audio playback

Tags: audio, actions-on-google

i'm new to **action on Googles** and right now doing R&D. I've created an audio skill on Alexa, and now want same for Google assistant as well. But i've few questions:

1- Can we return audio in response? my audios are about 1hour long, so can we play them in our action? In Alexa, we have audio player. Anything like that in assistant?

2- I didn't find any SDK, but devs are talking about it, so there must be some. Kindly share the link.

Thanks in anticipation.

**Update**:
I believe, SDK is actions-on-google. I've not explored it yet, but it's the SDK that i found for creating actions with node js
Link: [actions-on-google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/actions-on-google)

Comment: It's been almost a year since you asked this question, have you found a good solution to playing long audio clips via actions on google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actions support SSML which provides the playback of audio files: https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml#support_for_ssml_elements

At the moment there is a 120 seconds maximum duration for all the audio formats supported, but you can break up the audio and play them in sequence if they are longer.

If you have your own NLU, you can use the Actions SDK. If you don't have your own NLU, then you can use API.AI to create an action.

A node.js client library is available for either of these options: https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs

For any other developer questions, you should look at the actions documentation: https://developers.google.com/actions/develop/conversation

Comment: thanks. When you say "you can break up the audios and play them in sequence", what do you mean by that. Can we send multiple responses against a request (Each with audio snippet)? Or is there some player where we can enqueue multiple audio snippets and they will play one by one? @leon nicholls